# Add svg icon in the middle of an svg curved line

Tags: svg

I have a curved svg line like this

```
<path d="M70,260 C105,260 126,330 160,330"  
    style="stroke: #ff4444;stroke-width:2; fill:none;"/>
```

what I want is to add another svg (like https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/play-button_149657) in the middle of my line pointing to the end point.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve the result is a degenerate animation:

- Define the marker shape (`obj1` in the example below)
- Position the marker at the beginning of the curve (`track1` below; this is the path definition from your example).
- Specify an animated motion of the marker shape along the curve with some particular settings:

  - Explicit positioning along the track using `keyTimes`, `keyPoints` attributes, limiting the range of positions to exactly one point: the midpoint of the curve
  - Infinite duration, infinite repeat
  - Auto-rotation of the shape according to the orientation of the track curve ( `rotate` attribute )

Effectively there is no animation at all but the shape is positioned at the center of the curve, properly oriented.

**Example**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG object centered on path</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="200px" height="200px"
            viewBox="0 0 500 500"
            version="1.1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        >
            <defs>
                <path
                    id="obj1"
                    d="M11.18,0 L-2.5,10 -2.5,-10 Z"
                    stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="green"
                >
                </path>
                <path
                    id="track1"
                    d="M70,260 C105,260 126,330 160,330"
                    stroke="#ff4444" stroke-width="2" fill="none"
                />
            </defs>
            <use xlink:href="#track1"/>
            <use xlink:href="#obj1">
                <animateMotion
                    calcMode="linear"
                    dur="infinite"
                    repeatCount="infinite"
                    rotate="auto"
                    keyPoints="0.5;0.5"
                    keyTimes="0.0;1.0"
                >
                    <mpath xlink:href="#track1"/>
                </animateMotion>
            </use>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool, works fine. do you know if I can also use something like that as a google maps marker? as far as I know, on the marker you can only use the path as icon

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.

One way is to "cheat" a little and use a `<textPath>` and an arrow character.

[SVG marker-mid on specific point on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105713/svg-marker-mid-on-specific-point-on-path)

This is a little hacky, and may not work reliably on all browsers, but it may be good enough for your needs.

Another way is split the path in two (using [De Casteljau's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655135/divide-bezier-curve-into-two-equal-halves)), and use a `<marker>`.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 200 200 200" width="400">
  <defs>
    <marker id="Triangle"
      viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" 
      markerUnits="strokeWidth"
      markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
      orient="auto">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <path d="M 70,260
           C 87.5,260 101.5,277.5 115.375,295
           C 129.25,312.5 143,330 160,330"  
        style="stroke: #ff4444; stroke-width:2; fill:none; marker-mid:url(#Triangle)"/>
</svg>
```

There are other ways using Javascript. For example, you could use the `SVGPathElement.getPointAtLength()` method to find the coordinates of the centre of the path. Then position a triangle at that location.